# Saving Glassfish JDBC Configuration

Tags: configuration, database-connection, glassfish-3, connection-pooling

I recently had to re-install Glassfish 3.1.2 from scratch and I found myself spending way too much time re-configuring the JDBC Connection Pools and Resources (copy/paste from another source was not an option). Many applications use the server and there are plenty of things to remember when configuring JDBC connectivity.

Is there a way to "save" the Glassfish JDBC configuration to a file so that I can easily upload it to a new version of the server (or a new server in another machine) without losing my sanity again? A quick hack would also be highly appreciated as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server scoped application resources are stored in the *domain.xml* file within the `<resources>` element. There are `<jdbc-resource>` and `<jdbc-connection-pool>` elements which store your connections. From my experience you can copy those elements from one *domain.xml* file to another (at least for all 3.x versions of Glassfish).

Application scoped resources can be stored in *glassfish-resources.xml* files which need to go into the *META-INF* dir for an EAR and in *WEB-INF* for a WAR. They will be deployed together with an application and can only be accessed by this application. More information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/giydj.html).

Comment: I am using embedded glassfish and modified the domain.xml as you said but when I use '@Resource' for jdbc connections the look up fails. I have posted a question regarding this over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824478/failed-to-inject-datasource-using-resource-in-ejb3-0-embedded-glassfish
Can you please help

Comment: Just to add to this, while you can use `glassfish-resources.xml` to add application-scoped resources like the answer suggests, I think you can also use it to add _server-scoped_ resources using `asadmin add-resources glassfish-resources.xml`.